# Java balanced expressions check {[( )]} with multiple line

Tags: java

I have small code to check balance expressions {[( )]}.

In `main` I used:

```
String s = reader.nextLine();
System.Out.println (process(s));
```

Code:

```
public static boolean process(String s) {
    Stack<Character> stack  = new Stack<Character>();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(c == '[' || c == '(' || c == '{' ) {     
            stack.push(c);
        } else if(c == ']') {
            if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '[') {
                return false;
            }
        } else if(c == ')') {
            if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '(') {
                return false;
            }           
        } else if(c == '}') {
            if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '{') {
                return false;
            }
        }   
    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

It's ok if

```
Input : Hello (the [first] I will see in (heaven) is a score list).
Output : True
```

But if I have input with multiple it not work

```
Input : So when I die (the [first] I will see in (heaven) is a score list).

[ first in ] ( first out ).
Half Moon tonight (At least it is better than no Moon at all].

Output : True
```

Real output must be :

```
True
True 
False
```

I don't know why ? Please help me.

Comment: How are you reading the inputs? Maybe you are only passing the first line to the process method

Comment: How do you call process method?

Comment: I used String `s = reader.nextLine();`

Comment: Reading input from a file?

Comment: Your function looks fine, add the code who call it

Comment: I just edited my post.

Comment: Note that the `Stack` class is out-dated. Even its own Javadoc suggests to use implementations of the `Deque` interface instead. Like `ArrayDeque`. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html): *"A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class. For example: `Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();`"*

Comment: Does it print only "True" if so it's because you read only the first time and call the function only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are using `reader.nextLine()`, I assume your `reader` is a `java.util.Scanner`

You are only passing the first line, so run through all the lines of the input, and ignore the empty ones:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
while(reader.hasNext()) {
  String s = reader.nextLine();
  if(s.trim().length() > 0) {
    System.out.println (process(s));
  }
}
```

This should call `process` 3 times, with the following Strings:

- `So when I die (the [first] I will see in (heaven) is a score list).`
- `[ first in ] ( first out ).`
- `Half Moon tonight (At least it is better than no Moon at all].`